# How to solve "'this' implicitly has type 'any'" when Typescript checking classic JS class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some old code that uses classic JS classes that I want to type check. For example:

```
/**
 * @constructor
 */
function Test() {
    this.x = 1;
}
```

However when I run `tsc --noImplicitThis --noEmit --allowJs --checkJs test.js` to type check it, I get the following error:

```
test.js:5:5 - error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.

5     this.x = 1;
      ~~~~
```

I haven't been able to find any type annotation to fix this error, either by looking at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JsDoc-support-in-JavaScript or just by guessing. Is there a way?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://usejsdoc.org/tags-member.html?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's `noImplicitThis` which produces that error. You need to use a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters) to specify what the type of `this` is expected to be.

When using JSDoc you can use a [`@this` annotation](https://jsdoc.app/tags-this.html):

```
/**
 * @constructor
 * @this Test
 */
function Test() {
    this.x = 1;
}
```

In Typescript this is written as `function Test(this: Point) { ... }`.

Comment: He's using the typescript compiler to check **javasscript**, he can't use ts type annotation in JS. He probably needs some jsdoc annotations to satisfy the compiler...

Comment: At least that is my interpretation of the command line to the compiler `--checkJs test.js`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yep, you're definitely right. I read over that line too quickly.

Comment: Great, thank you! `@this` isn't mentioned on the Typescript wiki. I've edited your answer to directly answer the question.